# eclipse: validate xml with xsd

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd

does anyone know if it is possible to validate an xml with an xsd while i am editing the xml in eclipse?

this is how my xml begins:

```
<root 
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../definitions.xsd">
```

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right click and Validate. If it is not validated, then Eclipse cannot reach the XSD file. Is definitions.xsd in the parent directory of the XML? You can also define [XML catalog](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLCatalog/XMLCatalogTutorial.html) entries for your xsds. Anyway, if everything is fine, during saving it should validate XML. Validation usually come together with code completion of elements and attributes. They usually both work or neither.

UPDATE:

Picture to make validate action more clear:
[image]

Comment: where exactly is this validate that i should click?

Comment: thanks for the picture. it seems i really have the wrong eclipse since i dont see that menuitem.

Comment: then the problem is that you do not use XML editor for editing xml. Right click on the file in package explorer, and click on open-with and choose xml editor.

Comment: i have posted a screenshot of my context menu

Comment: If you go to about box in help, and you click on the icon of WTP (webtools platform), what is the version of feature called "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools"? Since you use android, I suppose you use eclipse 3.5? Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure this is doing what a lot of people think it is. I can deliberately change the XSD file name in the `schemaLocation` tag to something errornous and I still get a valid response out of Eclipse. It seems to check for well-formedness but not attempt or fail on XSD validation.

Comment: @8bitjunkie if the xsd is not found, eclipse checks only well formedness. But you get a warning in the problems view for sure

Answer (score 5):

I found out why the validate option doesn't show up. It happens when you browse files in your local filesystem. You should promote folder to a project, or just add xml and xsd files to some temporary project. Then validate as well as many other options should appear in contex menu.

I'm using eclipse 3.5.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: It would be good to put this in your (edited) answer, so people will see it.

Comment: How can you promote a folder to a project?

Answer (score 1):

It should be automatically-"on the fly" if you have the XSD file declared at the top.

Comment: thanks, yes i have it defined see my edit. but it doesnt seem to do any validation

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C).
I have taken both files, put them in eclipse, changed the UK entry to something else like RU, saved the file - and I got an error.

Comment: You don't even have to save the file. It'll show an error even before you save it.

Comment: hmm, what eclipse edition do you use? i have eclipse for java.

Comment: I have PDT (eclipse for PHP), but the XML support should be in most (if not all) editions.
Which version do you use ?
Try downloading the latest one.

Comment: This works, if xsd is declared with schemaLocation https://metamug.com/article/auto-complete-xml-editor-with-xsd-and-validations.html