# Problem validating XML against XSD with Eclipse/ADT - no "Validate" context menu entry

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation

Im trying to get Eclipse to validate an XML file I've created against a schema I've also created but it's not working, I don't have a "Validate" entry in the context menu.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 with ADT 10.0.1 and in Help -> About -> Installation details, Plug-ins tab I have Eclipse XML Editors and Tools version 1.1.103.

According to what I've found on both Eclipse's website and other questions on SO I should be able to right click on the XML file and click on "Validate". My context menu has no "Validate" entry and everything I find assumes it's there. I've gone into Eclipse Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Validation and ticked "Enable markup validation" but that hasn't changed anything..

Also changing the noNamespaceSchemaLocation value to something incorrect doesn't give me any errors when saving the XML file. I have no idea what I'm missing here

The idea was for the properties pane in Eclipse to show a dropdown for the element "name" attribute showing the valid values, which I'm hoping will happen once I can validate against the XSD.

### Similar questions

[eclipse: validate xml with xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194129/eclipse-validate-xml-with-xsd) just like me, no solution found even though the answer is accepted. Comments mention Web Tools Platform, which is installed.

[XML validation and auto-complete in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359239/xml-validation-and-auto-complete-in-eclipse) I have done what the accepted answer mentions

### Files

They're probably terrible, I haven't done much XML before.

`res/xml/magicks.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<magicks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="magicksschema.xsd">

<magick name="Haste" description="Increases the wizard's movement speed by up to double for 10 seconds.">
    <combination>
        <element name="Lightning"/>
        <element name="Arcane" />
        <element name="Fire" />
    </combination>
</magick>
</magicks>
```

`res/xml/magicksschema.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="magicks">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="magick" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="combination">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="element" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="name">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Water" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Life" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Shield" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Cold" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Lightning" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Arcane" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Earth" />
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="Fire" />
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

### Edit

- Updated schema to @Per Normann's version

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is not correct, specifically w.r.t. how you declare attributes.

1) attributes are declared directly on the type, not as part of a sequence.

2) you defined the element <element> to be enumeration restricted, not the attribute "name".

This schema matches your XML (and eclipse validation works fine).

```
<xs:element name="magicks">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="magick" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="combination">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="element" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="name">
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Water" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Life" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Shield" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Cold" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Lightning" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Arcane" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Earth" />
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="Fire" />
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                            </xs:attribute>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my schema! The examples I looked at only declared one attribute and I noticed sequences were used for multiple elements so I made that bit up :)

I'm still not able to validate in Eclipse though, and it's actually giving me a parsing error (on the last line: "no element found") for the new schema. I had weird parsing errors while writing the original schema too. Maybe my Eclipse installation is broken?